# Label элемент затирает нарисованные фигуры в PictureBox

Tags: winforms, label, picturebox, рисование, tooltip

Имеется поле для рисования в виде **PictureBox** в форме. Для того, чтобы видеть текущие координаты положения мышки добавлен **Label** элемент. Это элемент прикреплён к курсору пока последний в поле `PictureBox`.

Код **ToolTip** для курсора мыши:

```
public Label coordToolTip = new Label() { BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke, AutoSize = true };
```

Добавление **Tooltip** в **PictureBox**:

```
this.pictureBox1.Controls.Add(coordToolTip);
```

События обслуживающие включение/выключение/перемещение **Label** для курсора:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    coordToolTip.Visible = false;
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.pictureBox1.Image == null)
        return;

    coordToolTip.Visible = true;
    this.Cursor = CursorUtil.CreateCursorNoResize(new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Crosshair), 16, 16);
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.pictureBox1.Image == null)
        return;

    int offsetX = coordToolTip.Size.Width + (e.X + 15) > this.pictureBox1.Width ? -(coordToolTip.Size.Width + 10) : 10;
    int offsetY = coordToolTip.Size.Height + (e.Y + 15) > this.pictureBox1.Height ? -(coordToolTip.Size.Height + 10) : 10;

    Point location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    location.Offset(offsetX, offsetY);
    coordToolTip.Location = location;
    coordToolTip.Text = "X: " + e.X + "\nY: " + e.Y;
}
```

Следующим кодом рисую фигуры из массива:

```
List<IntIntHolder> array = SHAPES[index];
Point[] points = new Point[array.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
{
    IntIntHolder holder = array[i];
    points[i].X = holder.getKey();
    points[i].Y = holder.getValue();
}

Graphics graph = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2);
graph.DrawPolygon(pen, points);
```

В итоге я получаю всё как и задумывалось. НО! Как только **Label** элемент вслед за курсором проходит над нарисованной фигурой, так фигура в этом месте стирается словно ластиком. Само изображение **PictureBox** не меняется.

Но при выполнении этого кода

```
this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

перед исчезновением всех фигур они появляются/прорисовываются заново и после удаляются.

**Вопрос:** подскажите как это исправить (где я накосячил) или если способ реализовать похожий функционал более правильно.

Comment: Начнём строго, что рисуете вы не на изображении, которое размещено в `PicrureBox`, а на самом контроле. Так и задумывалось?

Comment: Ну и для справки - `PictureBox` предназначен для отображения картинок, но не для редактирования. Для редактирования стандартных контролов нет, нужно писать руками.

Comment: @rdorn Спасибо за ответ. Но проблема решена созданием UserControl который вмещает в себя и рисование произвольных фигур и прочие стандартные элементы и свойства. В итоге всё работает даже лучше чем первоначально задумывалось. К сожалению ссылку на форум где был взят пример проекта я не могу найти.

Comment: Это хороший вариант решения :) можете оформить как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение своей проблемы нашёл в коде одного безымянного поляка (судя по локализации). Сам проект нашёл на одном русскоязычном форуме (ссылку потерял на тему), в одной из тем которого обсуждалась похожая моей проблема.

Смысл решения очень прост. Создаётся UserControl который включает в себя разные геометрические фигуры. Он же занимается их отрисовкой и редактированием (изменение размеров и перетаскивание). Немного расширив функционал я добавил эффекты для курсора непосредственно внутри самого контрола.

Ссылку на проект [прилагаю](https://yadi.sk/d/5VqtrYq95idkag). Возможно кому-то пригодится для наглядного изучения способов рисования в WinForms.